# Prop: there is $\mathbf{y} \in R^k$ such that $\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Prop:** Let's suppose that $k \geq 2$ and $\mathbf{x}\in R^k$, then there is $\mathbf{y} \in R^k$ such that $\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} = 0$

**Pf:** Let $\mathbf{x}= (x_1,...,x_k)$ and $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,...,y_k)$. By definition, if two vectors are orthogonal, $\cos(\theta) = 0 \iff \theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Then, $||\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}||^2 = ||\mathbf{x}||^2 +||\mathbf{y}^2|| \implies (x_1+y_1,...,x_k+y_k)(x_1+y_1,...,x_k+y_k) = (x_1,...x_k)(x_1,...,x_k)+(y_1,...y_k)(y_1,...,y_k)$

$$\sum^{k}_{i=1}(x_i+y_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{k}(x^2_i + y^2_i) \implies \sum^{k}_{i=1}\biggr((x_i+y_i)^2 -(x^2_i + y^2_i)\biggr) = 0$$

$$\sum^{k}_{i=1}\biggr((x_i+y_i)^2 -((x_i+y_i)^2-2x_iy_i)\biggr) =\sum^{k}_{i=1}\biggr((x_i+y_i)^2 -(x_i+y_i)^2+2x_iy_i)\biggr)=0$$

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k} 2x_iy_i = 0 \implies \sum_{i=1}^{k}x_iy_i = 0$$

Then, there is $x_i, y_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_iy_i = 0$ and $y_i \neq 0$.

Comment: This doesn't prove your proposition. It just proves that if $cos \theta = 0$ then $\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} = 0 $. Given $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \cdots, x_k)$ try constructing $y$ using $x_i's$. For example if $k=3$, take $y = (-x_2,x_1,0)$ if $x_1$ or $x_2$ not zero.

Answer (score 3):

From a combinatorial point-of-view, let $\mathcal{S}$ denote the set of indices of non-zero values in $x$. Then for $k \in \bar{\mathcal{S}}$, you're free to pick any non-zero value of $y_k$. Now we have two cases:

$1)$ If $\vert \mathcal{S} \vert $ is even, you can pick $y_{k} = \pm \frac{1}{x_k}$ (where $k \in \mathcal{S})$, where the number of negative and positive entries of $y_k$ ($k \in \mathcal{S}$) are equal.

$2)$ If $\vert \mathcal{S} \vert $ is odd, you can pick one $y_k = 0$ (where $k \in \mathcal{S})$, then go back to case $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Given ${\bf x}$ we want ${\bf y}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_iy_i = 0$ and not all $y_i$ zero. Given that ${\bf x}$ is fixed, this is simply a liner homogenous equation in k variables. We can assume that at least one $x_i$ is non zero. This system cannot have a unique solution (which would be each $y_i=0$), since the number of variables $k\geq 2>1$.